# NSDate variable persistence

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

```
NSDate *sampleDate = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%@", sampleDate);
```

The above date will change when time zone of the device is changed. Is this the expected behavior?

If we store a date in a variable, it should not change even if we change the timezone of the device right?

I know its better to use `timeIntervalSince1970` or `referrenceDate` but again why a pre set variable is being modified if we just change the timezone..

Comment: The date doesn't change. It is an absolute point in time. The output you get from printing the date in the current time zone will change.

Comment: Additional to Paulw11, use NSCalendar to display the date in the time zone etc. you need. NSDate internally is always UTC.